# Achieve Vertical Grid View in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-layout, gridview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My Code :::

```
@Composable
fun VerticalImageCards(toolsList: List<HealthTool>) {
    val domainName = stringResource(id = R.string.media_url)

    FlowRow(mainAxisSpacing = 8.dp,
        crossAxisSpacing = 16.dp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
        mainAxisSize = SizeMode.Wrap) {
        for (i in toolsList) {
            val imgUrl = "$domainName${i.url}"
            ToolsCardLayout(cardTitle = i.title, imgUrl = imgUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun ToolsCardLayout(
    imgUrl: String,
    cardTitle: String,
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.clickable {}) {
        AsyncImage(model = imgUrl,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(32.dp)
            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.schedule),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 8.dp),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit)
        }
    }
    Card(modifier = Modifier
        .height(44.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text = cardTitle,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 8.dp, bottomEnd = 8.dp)))
    }
}
```

Code Explanation:::

I'm getting a list of tools details which is having tool image, title, description from server.

imgURl -> url for image

cardTitle -> tool's name

Problem :::
Card is taking the whole width. Earlier, I used weight(1f) when the data was hardcoded and I don't have to retrieve it from backend. Also, I'm going to use it on the Homescreen, so the grid shouldn't be scrollable.

[PLEASE VISIT THIS DRIVE LINK FOR MORE DETAILS, I have added code snippet and images + screen recording for better understanding](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Xe8863b-x3NJlyfqMHl6VT2WX_iqkHRI?usp=sharing)

Comment: Make link publicly visible without requesting permission.

Comment: so sorry, I have updated the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use official [LazyVerticalGrid](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists)

```
@Composable
fun VerticalImageCards(toolsList: List<HealthTool>) {
    val domainName = stringResource(id = R.string.media_url) {

     LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            modifier = modifier,
            state = rememberLazyGridState()
        ) {
       
         items(toolsList) { 
           val imgUrl = "$domainName${it.url}"
           ToolsCardLayout(cardTitle = it.title, imgUrl = imageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thnq @Gastón. it's working.